# R Stackbar plot with Binary variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I want to use ggplot, my data is as such

```
x <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE) #Logical
y <- c(0,1,1,0,1,0) #Numeric
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
```

I want to create a stacked barchart showing percentage...This seems like it should be an easy problem but somehow I'm getting this messed up and can't find a straight answer.

I've tried this

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y))+geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')


ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = factor(y), fill = y))+geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')
```

The second one looks closer but the axis squashes everything to sum to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `position = 'stack'` and the `y-axis` to the `sum` of `y` values, like this:

```
ggplot(data = dat, 
       aes(x = x, y = sum(y), fill = y)) +
       geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity')
```

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, fill = factor(y))) +
  geom_bar()
```

In particular, `geom_bar()` has a default for its aggregation to count up the rows (`stat = "count"`). You'd use `stat = "identity"` when you had already pre-calc'd the counts.